# Server Sent Events (SSE) with Qt

Tags: qt, http

I already saw several libraries for Server Sent Events, unfortunately, not for Qt. I also looked at the specification of SSE (just plain HTTP) and it seems that implementing SSE in Qt would require to:

- Use QNetworkAccessManager in streaming mode (download)
- Accept the content type header of SSE: `application/events-stream`
- Reconnect when the connection is lost or closed
- Attach a slot to the QNAM when new bytes are received (check for `data : {...}`)

I'm not sure if it's so "easy"? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a small demo with Qt and Server Sent Events.
The demo connects to a given EventSource URL (first argument) and prints every event to the command line.

Qt supports SSE out of the box since SSE is pure HTTP with a reconnection layer on top of it.

1. Prepare the request: set the `text/event-stream` accept header, allow redirects, disable the cache.

```
QNetworkRequest Network::Manager::prepareRequest(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Accept"), QByteArray(ACCEPT_HEADER));
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork); // Events shouldn't be cached
    return request;
}
```

2. Connect the `readyRead` signal to a slot.

```
void Network::Manager::getResource(const QUrl &url)
{
    qDebug() << "GET resource:" << url;
    QNetworkRequest request = this->prepareRequest(url);
    m_reply = this->QNAM()->get(request);
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(streamReceived()));
}
```

3. Every time a new event is received by the QNetworkAccessManager, you can read it using `readAll`. We reset the retries counter after every successful event.

```
void Network::Manager::streamReceived()
{
    qDebug() << "Received event from stream";
    qDebug() << QString(m_reply->readAll()).simplified().replace("data: ", "");
    qDebug() << "-----------------------------------------------------";
    m_retries = 0;
}
```

4. In case we lost the connection or the connection times out, the `finished()` signal is triggered of the QNetworkAccessManager. We try to reconnect to the event source (We connected this slot to the signal when we created our QNetworkAccessManager instance):

```
void Network::Manager::streamFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Stream finished:" << reply->url();
    qDebug() << "Reconnecting...";
    if(m_retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
        m_retries++;
        this->getResource(reply->url());
    }
    else {
        qCritical() << "Unable to reconnect, max retries reached";
    }
}
```

You can find the demo here: https://github.com/DylanVanAssche/Qt-Server-Sent-Events-Demo

Comment: Do you know how to kill the connection from the client side (Qt side) ? Or how to send more data to the server ?

Comment: @Omarito Server Sent Events is normal HTTP stream, it works in chunks, just like HTTP 1.1 chunks, but with some additional controls and advantages of HTTP 2.0. So sending more data while still receiving an Event stream from the server is not possible, for these use cases, WebSockets is the way to go. WebSockets allows you to communicate in both ways independently.